# How to cache items from hot observable into cold observable right after subscription

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

I have one global hot observable, which producing values independently. I have transformed global observable to derived hot. I need to create cold observable, which will replay all items from derived hot observable with keeping derived hot observable as **hot** without replay.

```
ConsoleOutput output = new();
ConsoleKey? pressedKey = null;
IDisposable? coldSourceSubscription = null;

var globalHotSource = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Publish().AutoConnect();
var derivedHotSource = globalHotSource.DelaySubscription(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));
var derivedColdSource = derivedHotSource; // How to make it cold?

globalHotSource.Subscribe(x => output.AddToLine(0, x, "Initial HOT:"));
derivedHotSource.Subscribe(x => output.AddToLine(1, x, "Derived HOT:"));

while ((pressedKey = Console.ReadKey().Key) != ConsoleKey.Escape || coldSourceSubscription is null)
{
    if (pressedKey != ConsoleKey.Enter) continue;
    coldSourceSubscription = derivedColdSource.Subscribe(x => output.AddToLine(2, x, "Derived COLD:"));
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

`ConsoleOutput` is a helper class and here is the code for it:

```cs
class ConsoleOutput
{
    readonly List<List<string>> _lines = new(Enumerable.Repeat<List<string>>(null, 128));
    public ConsoleOutput()
    {
        Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
            .ObserveOn(TaskPoolScheduler.Default)
            .Subscribe(_ => Refresh());
    }

    public void AddToLine(int lineNumber, object item, string initialItemFormat)
    {
        (_lines[lineNumber] ??= new List<string>() { string.Format(initialItemFormat, lineNumber) }).Add(item.ToString());
    }

    private void Refresh()
    {
        var output = _lines.Where(x => x is { })
            .Select(x => x.Aggregate(string.Empty, (x, y) => x + " " + y))
            .DefaultIfEmpty()
            .Aggregate((x, y) => x + "\n" + y);

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}
```

And here is the sample output from console:

```
 Initial HOT: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
 Derived HOT: 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
 Derived COLD: 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
```

First the code will produce items on the first line for global observable, after 4 seconds the derived one will produce it's items on the second line and the last one will be cold (which is not cold at the moment) which will produce values after user presses 'Enter' in console. I need for cold observable to show the same values, as the derived one.

The easiest way I could think of to solve it is to use `ReplaySubject` and insert `.Do(x => replaySubject.OnNext(x))` to derived observable and then assign replaySubject as observable to the target cold observable. However, is it possible to achieve the same without using subject?

Comment: Have you tried to wrap the hot sequence in `Observable.Defer`?

Comment: @theodor-zoulias, thanks for suggestion. Defer doesn't work as expected when I apply it to the second hot observable. When I apply it to global hot observable then all three observables will return me same values starting from zero.

Comment: @vkolesnik - What is your understanding of what a hot observable is versus a cold one?

Comment: @Enigmativity, hot produces values despite any subscriptions, which means that each new subscriber will not receive values, which were produced before it's subscription. Also, not all subscribers will receive the same starting values depending on subscription time. Cold observable will start producing values only after subscription and each subscriber will receive the same sequence.

Comment: @vkolesnik - You got Hot correct. Cold behaves as you say, but can also produce different sequences for each subscriber. For example, a random number generator would be a cold sequence.